# Wrong SIZE, MAXSIZE and FILEGROWTH?

Tags: sql-server

I know that basically while creating a database, the model system DB is copied so based on the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

1. Why the initial size is 3MB for PRIMARY file and 1MB for LOG If the documentation clearly says that It should be 8MB for versions above 2016 and 1MB for anything lower (I'm on this category as I'm using 2014)
2. I understand that a log file could grow to 2TB maximum but why the Model database says unlimited and the STACK database says limited to 2TB?
3. Assuming that the actual default size is indeed 3MB and 1MB, why on the disk, I see 2240 KB and 560 KB?

Comment: 1. I want to see documentation that you are quoting, as these number are highly case specific i.e. you change them for your specific DB. 2. 2TB = unlimited for Log Files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server). 3 Windows and SQL Server compute sizes differently: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142076/querying-true-physical-database-file-sizes

Answer (score 0):

1. Although the [documentation for 2016 and later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database) do say that the initial size is 8MB, I can't find references to the 1MB initial size in the [2005](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.90).aspx), [2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.100).aspx), [2008 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.105).aspx), [2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.110).aspx) and [2014](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.120).aspx) versions. I don't have a 2014 version at hand but in 2008 R2 the initial size of model is also 3MB, so it seems to be the default initial value (maybe you confused initial size with the default autogrow value of 1MB).
2. In this point the documentation doesn't seem to be 100% accurate, because in all versions prior to 2016 they list the default autogrow of the primary data file as 10% when the real value is 1MB. Also, for the model log file the maximum size is Unrestricted/Unlimited (if you do `select * from model..sysfiles` the value of the `size` column in log row is -1) but when you create a new database the maximum size of the log file is indeed 2TB, I think that this is explained by this paragraph of the [2014 documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.120).aspx):

   > If you modify the model database, all databases created afterward will inherit those changes. For example, you could set permissions or database options, or add objects such as tables, functions, or stored procedures. **File properties of the model database are an exception, and are ignored except the initial size of the data file**.

   So I think that the documentation just coalesce the two facts, meaning that the maximum value of the log file for new databases is 2TB.
3. Because that column of SSMS don't shows decimal values, so the real value has to be rounded to an integer. Instead of using `ROUND()` probably they use `CEILING()` just to be in safe side (at least for low values, if not a size of e.g. 490KB would be reported as 0MB).